# Firestore query, exclude documents based on optional bool

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use a bool to hide certain firestore documents holding map annotations from the results. However, I'm noticing its a challenge when the bool I'm using is optional and doesn't exist at all on most documents.

My query looks like:

```
let queries = queryBounds.map { bound -> Query in
            return db.collection("venues")
                .whereField("flagForDeletion", in: [false, NSNull()])
                .order(by: "geohash")
                .start(at: [bound.startValue])
                .end(at: [bound.endValue])
            
        }
```

But I currently dont get documents back where flagForDeletion does not exist.

Am I right in thinking that if I want a bool to hide/exclude certain documents, I had just better set it to a default on all documents?

Comment: Firestore queries are based on the presence of a document in the index(es) that the query uses. Documents that don't contain the field(s) you query on, will not be in the index(es) and thus won't be returned. Giving all documents a default value (I typically start with `false`) is indeed the way to work around this behavior.